# Jquery Selecting different elements of the same class div

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have got these 3 divs:

[image]

which on click the view button changes the content:

[image]

So, yeah, I am using the classes for selecting, so when I click any of the "View chart" button from all 3, all the 3 divs changes as expected...but I want that particular div to change only. I can easily do this by giving each div it's own id and stuff but it would be the inefficient way of doing this, so I need it to be done using $(this) selectors, I just don't know how to select each div on it's own.

This is how the jQuery looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.beltrap').click(function(){
        $('.alert_content').toggleClass('alert_content2');
        $('.alert_content p').toggle('500');
        $('.alert_content img').toggle('500');
    });
});
```

Okay here is the HTML markup, rest 2 are the same:

```
<div class="alert">
<div class="uptrap"><h2>LOTE Alerted</h2></div>
<div class="alert_content">
<p><strong>LOTE</strong> alerted at$1.00 then reached <strong>$22.00</strong> for gains of over 2000%.</p>
<img src="img/graph2.png">
</div>
<div class="beltrap"><div class="gg_button">View Chart</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `.alert_content` a children of `.beltrap` ?

Comment: Please post the HTML markup related to it also. That would help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. Beginning from `.beltrap` it selects the parent container and searches inside the parent container for `.alert_content`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.beltrap').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find('.alert_content').toggleClass('alert_content2');
        $(this).parent().find('.alert_content p').toggle('500');
        $(this).parent().find('.alert_content img').toggle('500');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.beltrap').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('alert_content2');
    $(this).find('p').toggle('500');
    $(this).find('img').toggle('500');
});
```

Comment: I think it does selects each element, but still not what I expected: http://puu.sh/3pmSq.png

Answer (score 0):

use this.

markup

```
<div class="gg_button" onclick="gg_buttonclick(this)">View Chart</div>
```

script

```
    function gg_buttonclick(ref)
    {
      now ref hold the reference to the clicked div.
      do your stuff
    }
```

Comment: I really want to keep it all in external sheet, so that if the client wants to change the click thing to hover, or dbl click, he can just do it in the js file, wouldnt have to worry about the markup at all. :)

But I really like the approach!

Comment: 'onclick' is just an attribute it doest not dependent on you external sheet. and you can also place the js function to the external js file.